# Need help in x and y trajectory

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, matlab-figure

I have an image of plot and i don't which tool is used for creating it, is it MATLAB or simulink. Here's an image I got from a paper and want to make my own image like this: 
[image]

i used 2D plot in MATLAB but this result are very different, i need x and y trajectory and my code is

```
 X=1;               %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 Y=0;               %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 Z=1;               %Your values and equations
 X=-10*X+10*Y;      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 Y=28*X-Y-X*Y;      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 Z=-(8/3)*Z+X*Y;    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 Vo = 10;               %Velocity 
 dt=0.002;
 alp=0.2;
 t= 0:200:5000;    %Time
 % x = X*10+dt*alp*(Vo * cos(Z) * t) ;
 x = Vo * cos(Z) * t ;
 y = Vo*sin(Z)*t;
 plot(t,x,'k'); hold on;
 plot(t,y,'r'); 
 legend('X-trajectory','Y-trajectory','Location','NorthEast')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you plot the `x(t),y(t)` trajectory?

```
plot( x, y, '--k' );
```

#### A Longer Version:

In mathematics, a "function" is a relation between `a` and `f(a)` such that each `a` has **at most** one value of `f(a)`. Thus if you look at the graph of `plot(a, f(a) );` you'll notice that each (imaginary) vertical line that you draw on the graph intersect the line you draw at most once.
So, what happens if you want to draw/represent mathematically curves that do not abide this rule (e.g., a circle or the trajectory you attached in your question)?
To represent such "self-intersecting" curves, you can have a parametric representation: you use a parameter (usually called `t`) then you represent the `x` and `y` coordinates of the curve as a functions of `t`, finally, you can plot them as `(x(t),y(t))`.

An example: a circle.
The parameter `t` in the range `-pi:pi`

```
>> t = -pi:0.01:pi;
```

Expressing `x(t)` and `y(t)` independently:

```
>> x_t = cos(t);
>> y_t = sin(t);
```

Now we can plot the curve

```
>> plot( x_t, y_t );
```

Note that the parameter `t` is not explicitly participating in the plot: it is not one of the axes.

Comment: please can you explain using a short code, it will help me learning